# How to Loop Through Variable Formats and Rename In SAS

Tags: loops, sas, rename, sas-macro

I have a dataset where each column represents a different month, year combination from February 2018 to December 2025.  These columns are stored as characters, but I would like to convert them to numeric.  Currently, the columns are named 'FEB_18', 'MAR_18', 'NOV_19', 'JUL_22' ect.

I would like to create a loop takes each variable and converts it to numeric. Originally, I used the following code, but this creates a new dataset for each iteration.

```
 %let months = JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC;

 %MACRO DOIT(Peak=); 

    %do i= 1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&Name.));
    %let Name2 = %scan(&months., &i.);
    %do j = 18 %to 25; 

proc sql;
    create table ppl as 
        select
        input(Label, Best12.) - 21916 as Contract format MMDDYY10., /* Excel to SAS Dates*/
        input(&Name2._&j., Best12.) as _&Name2._&j.
    from Transposed_&Peak.;
    %end;
    %end;
quit;


%mend DOIT; 
%DOIT(Peak = On);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this an import of an Excel pivot table ? Having the year/month as metadata (i.e. the year/month is the column name) can be problematic.  What other columns are in the data ?  How would you process the data by year, or months year over year ? Would a pivoted data structure (which would be a categorical form) be more useful (one row per id/year/month) ?  The categorical form allows SAS syntax such a `where` `class` `by`.

Comment: I am pulling the data from Bloomberg - financial futures data.  So each row is already an individual date. Each column identifies the contracted date.

Comment: Sounds like you are just asking how to move your `%do` loop from around SQL statement to the middle of the SQL statement?  Did you try moving it? What issues did you have?

Comment: Transpose to a long format. Recode the dates as desired since they're now a single variable and then transpose back to a wide format if you want. No macros and is fully dynamic for changes in your data, such as the addition of new columns.

Comment: Is your question how to generate a series of variable names?  Figure out which variables are in the pattern MON_YY?  Something else?

Comment: Is your actual question how to rename a variable with a name lke _NNNNN because the header cell in the original Excel file had an actual date value instead of a character string?

Answer (score 0):

The `CONTENTS` procedure will make the metadata (column names, types, column number,etc) of the data set available as data.  From that data you can construct the statements needed to perform the conversion

Example:

```
X_feb_20 = input(feb_20, ?? best12.);  * parse value in character variable into a numeric variable;
drop feb_20;  * drop character variable from output data set;
rename x_feb_20 = feb_20;  * change the name of the numeric variable back to the orginal;
```

So the chore is to do that pattern for all character columns in the data set whose name represents a `<mon>_<yy>`.  The test

```
input('01'||transtrn(name,'_','20'),anydtdte.) is not null
```

will identify such column names.

Here is an example macro that will perform the chores:

```
/* 
 * Fake some data to play with 
 */

%macro month_columns(from_month=, to_month=);

  %local index mon yy frstdate lastdate;

  %let frstdate = %sysevalf("01&from_month"D);
  %let lastdate = %sysevalf("01&to_month"D);

  %do date = %sysevalf("01&from_month"D) %to %sysevalf("01&to_month"D);
    %let date = %sysfunc(INTNX(MONTH,&date,0,E));

    %sysfunc(putn(&date,MONNAME3))_%sysfunc(putn(&date,YEAR2.))
  %end;

%mend;

data have;
  call streaminit(123);
  do stockid = 1 to 10;
    array futures $12 %month_columns(from_month=FEB2020, to_month=DEC2025);
    do over futures;
      futures = put(rand('uniform',50) + stockid * sin(_i_/40), 12.5);
    end;
    output;
  end;
run;

/* 
 * Chore macro
 */

%macro asnum_mon_yy_columns(data=, out=);

  %local index;

  proc contents noprint data=&data out=have_columns(keep=varnum name type);
  run;

  * SQLOBS will be number of rows (and thus names) that meet the date-like criteria ;

  proc sql noprint;
    select name into :name1-
    from have_columns
    where input('01'||transtrn(name,'_','20'),anydtdte.) is not null 
      and type = 2
    order by varnum
    ;
  quit;

  data &out;
    set &data;

    %do index = 1 %to &sqlobs;
      X_&&name&index = input(&&name&index,??best12.);
    %end;

    %if &sqlobs %then %do;
      drop   %do index = 1 %to &sqlobs;
                &&name&index
             %end;
      ;
      rename %do index = 1 %to &sqlobs;
                X_&&name&index = &&name&index
             %end;
      ;
    %end;
  run;

%mend;

/*
 * Invoke chore
 */

options mprint;

%asnum_mon_yy_columns(data=have, out=want)
```